# Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected statement

Tags: active-directory, vbscript

What is wrong with this script?

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim objRootDSE, strDNSDomain, adoConnection
Dim strBase, strFilter, strAttributes, strQuery, adoRecordset
Dim dtmStart, dtmEnd, strStart, strEnd
Dim strID, strFirst, strLast, strNTName

dtmEnd = Now()
dtmStart = DateAdd("d", -7, dtmEnd)
strStart = CStr(Year(dtmStart)) _
& Right("0" & CStr(Month(dtmStart)), 2) _
& Right("0" & CStr(Day(dtmStart)), 2) & "000000.0Z"
strEnd = CStr(Year(dtmEnd)) _
& Right("0" & CStr(Month(dtmEnd)), 2) _
& Right("0" & CStr(Day(dtmEnd)), 2) & "235959.0Z"

' Determine DNS domain name.
Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")

' Use ADO to search Active Directory.
Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set adoRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
adoRecordset.ActiveConnection = adoConnection

' Search entire domain.
strBase = "<LDAP://" & strDNSDomain & ">"

'For user accounts for people created in the last week
strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)" _
& "(whenCreated>=" & strStart & ")(whenCreated<=" & strEnd & "))"

' Comma delimited list of attribute values to retrieve.
strAttributes = "employeeID,sn,givenName,sAMAccountName"

' Construct the LDAP query.
strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"

' Run the query.
adoRecordset.Source = strQuery
adoRecordset.Open

' Enumerate the resulting recordset.
Do Until adoRecordset.EOF
' Retrieve values.
strID = adoRecordset.Fields("employeeID").Value
strLast = adoRecordset.Fields("sn").Value
strFirst = adoRecordset.Fields("givenName").Value
strNTName = adoRecordset.Fields("sAMAccountName").Value
Wscript.Echo """" & strID & """,""" & strLast & """,""" & strFirst
& """,""" & strNTName & """"
adoRecordset.MoveNext
Loop

' Clean up.
adoRecordset.Close
adoConnection.Close
```

```
cscript //nologo test.vbs > users.csv
```

returns

```
(53, 1) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected statement
```

Comment: Please read our FAQ before posting again.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an underscore line continuation at the end of the first line of this snippet:

```
Wscript.Echo """" & strID & """,""" & strLast & """,""" & strFirst
& """,""" & strNTName & """"
```

It should look like this:

```
Wscript.Echo """" & strID & """,""" & strLast & """,""" & strFirst _
& """,""" & strNTName & """"
```